# where can I find eclipse.ini in windows 8?

Tags: eclipse, google-play-services

I can not run my project after adding google play services to it. If I try to run it then I am getting this error `Unable to execute dex: GC overhead limit exceeded GC overhead limit`  I read  some posts about the problem where they say I have to modify the -XmsAm and -XmxBm paremeters in eclipse.ini. Where I can find eclipse.ini in Windows 8? I search the extracted eclipse directory as well as the workspace but nothing is there!

[image]

Comment: That file is in the same directory as the eclipse binary.

Comment: Hi,

Are you talking about Windows 8 phone?

If it is windows 8 desktop, the .ini file is at the same place than eclipse.exe.

You are talking about project, if it is in a Launch configuration , you need to update the VM arguments in arguments tab of your Run configuration.

regards,

Comment: Where is Eclipse located? Program Files? You may be running into a UAC file visualization problem in which case it will be in your virtual store under “%userprofile%\AppData\Local\VirtualStore\Program Files”.

Comment: Yes, Iam talking about Windos 8 Desktop. @kjbartel: I dont have VirtualStore in the local directory. I just have "Microsoft", "Microsoft Help" and "Temp" Please see screenshot of the exracted content of my eclipse directory.

Comment: You can see the ini file in the screenshot. It's the one with the cog.

Comment: Ok thanks I was confused because it does not have the end ini like in Linux ;)

Comment: Look like you have the 'Hide extensions for known file types' option set in Windows Explorer so it doesn't show the '.ini' part of the name

Answer (score -1, accepted):

For myself (Windows 8), the eclipse.ini file is in the install directory of eclipse